# If $\dim \ker T=4, \dim \ker T^3=9, \dim \ker T^4=11$. Then, Find $\dim \ker T^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T: \mathbb C^{11} \rightarrow  \mathbb C^{11} $ be a linear transformation, such that $\dim \ker T=4, \dim \ker T^3=9, \dim \ker T^4=11$. Then, Find $\dim \ker T^2.$

**Attempt:** We have : $\ker T \subset \ker T^2 \subset \ker T^3 \subset \ker T^4$ where $T$ is clearly nilpotent with index $4$

$\implies \dim \ker T <  \dim \ker T^2 <  \dim \ker T^3 <  \dim \ker T^4$

Thus,  $\dim \ker T^2 $ can assume values from $\{5,6,7,8 \}$.

How do I move forward from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the Jordan form od $T$. We have
$$\dim \ker T^k -\dim \ker T^{k-1}= \text{ number of 0-blocks of size} \ge k.$$

Therefore, we have $4$ Jordan $0$-blocks, of which two are of size exactly $4$ (since $\dim \ker T^5 = 11$ as well). This covers $8$ columns out of the entire $11\times 11$ Jordan matrix , so we have $3$ more columns to account for. Those $3$ columns must contain exactly two blocks, so we have exactly one $1$-block and one $2$-block.

Therefore there are $3$ blocks of size $\ge 2$ so from the formula above we conclude that $$\dim\ker T^2 = \dim \ker T + 3 = 7.$$